GStreamer vaapih264dec output appers scrambled when used with xvimagesink or glimagesink
I am trying to use Gstreamer with the vaapih264dec decoder to view a movie on my computer.
I am using the following command and it appears to be successfully decoding the video, however it is not getting the right formatting for the data it passes to glimagesink.
It seems like there is some kind of "span" or "spacing" used as I get a grid of scrambled data.
Is anyone familiar with why the data looks like this? Also is there a gstreamer plugin I can used to format it properly before sending to glimagesink? If not any tips on what the order is would be appreciated.
I made a test image with a gradient of red on the horizontal and blue on the vertical, to try and figure out how to decode the image. I am ultimately using a custom gstreamer plugin for video sink output so I can shuffle the data around with numpy as required once I know what the formatting is.
GST_DEBUG=3 GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=./ LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=./red_blue_2d_gradient_test_image.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapih264dec ! autovideoconvert ! glimagesink

Here is the dot graph

The input image used to generate the video that was tested

The screenshot of the output image

I am hoping to either find a gstreamer plugin that can correct the formatting of the data.
Or alternatively if someone can tell me what reformatting is necessary and how to determine what reformatting is necessary on different media files streams I can write something myself to conert it.
I counted and it looks like there are 15 horizontal blocks and 34 vertical stripes for a total of 510 blocks. This is slighly less than half the vertical resolution which is 1920x1080. I am wondering if perhaps each block is two video lines combined. The source video has no black borders anywhere so I'm not entirely sure why the 15 blocks at the bottom have a portion of them that is black.
Also forgot to mention I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with gstreamer 1.16.3.
It seems like the issue is a known bug that was fixed in version 1.20 and related to dmabuff negotiations
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1137
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/merge_requests/2459
It also seems like vaapi is probably being deprecated so I should switch to vah264dec instead. I probably need to upgrade my system.
I tried manually building gstreamer-vaapi and patching out the dma-buff capability, but I can't get it to find a valid display when I build it for some reason. I would probably need to build it from the the ubuntu 20.04 package source repository instead of from the freedesktop git repo. I am guessing they have some customizations or something.
I also tried manually specifying a capfilter in between vaapih264dec and autovideoconvert to force it not to use a dmabuf, and it didn't seem to make any difference.
vaapih264dec ! capsfilter caps='video/x-raw' ! autovideoconvert
